# Particle Sytem Tree Leafs Hollow View

Tags: rendering, texturing, particles, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I am trying to make a tree asset for the game. I made a hair particle system with a collection of leafs. I clicked the make the instances real button. It looks normal before I join them together. But joining together makes the leafs transparent according to the camera view.
**Here is a video of the problem I uploaded to youtube:**
https://youtu.be/UYI1a6sJv6M

[image: Places you see green are actually the backside of the leafs]

It also occurs in render mode which you can see in the video. Also, I don't know if it is related or not but, there is another issue: In render mode, my leaf planes (using a .png transparent file, I added a material to the plane) seem varying color when looking from behind and front. Normally it should be orangish color, but color changes to yellowish color from behind. It also occurs after I get a render shot (pressing f12). I am also adding the material screen shot.

I tried to solve the problem with different joining methods, changing eeve to cycles, changing the material etc. But I couldn't work it out because I don't even know what the problem is. Could you help me out?

Edit:
[image: material settings]

[image]

Comment: What do the material settings look like? Just a guess: Have you enabled [Show Backfaces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#sorting-problem)? It should be disabled when you use the *Alpha-Blending* option for transparency.

Comment: I checked what you suggested. It is unlicked if you mean the backface culling option. I also uploaded the material setting ss. Is it possbile this is because the image texture node has sRgb alpha mode when I also use the alpha information from the .png picture in the same image texture node?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess it's a sorting problem as described in the documentation (but I could be wrong). The sRGB Color Space should be no problem. - The *Show Backface* option is only visible when you set the *Blend Mode* option to *Alpha Blend*. Then you can untick the checkbox if it's enabled. Alternatively, try *Alpha Hash* which does not have that sorting problem but adds a little noise.

Comment: You are using *Alpha Clip* for the *Blend Mode*. I'm not that familiar with this option. The documentation reads: *"The previous color will be overwritten by the surface color, but only if the alpha value is above the Clip Threshold value."*. Maybe it already helps if you lower the threshold. 0.5 seems to be too high because the leaves in the front are clipped.

Comment: Alright, thanks. It solved the problem with setting Alpha Hashed both the leafs and tree. Now, however, there is still the problem change of color when looking back of the leaf plane.